# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'latitude' _ Python

Tags: python, geolocalização

Já vi algumas questões parecidas com a minha aqui, mas como sou muito novo em Python, não estou conseguindo idenificar meu erro. Meu programa é bem curtinho, eu simplesmente quero encontrar as coordenadas de latitude e longitude a partir de nomes de municípios que eu leio de um CSV (ListaEnd.csv). Ao rodar o programa recebo a mensagem de erro:

****Traceback (most recent call last):
File "teste2.py", line 26, in 
print(location.address)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'address'****

O programa é:

```
import geopandas as gpds
import pandas as pds 
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

df = pds.read_csv("ListaEnd.csv", encoding='UTF8')

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="Intro Geocode")
location = geolocator.geocode(df['Municipio'])

print(location.address)
print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
```

Qualquer ajuda é muito válida, amigos. Desde já, valeu demais!!!

Comment: Qual o valor de `df['Municipio']`, tens uma string com o endereço ou talvez uma lista?

Comment: df['Municipios'] são nomes de municípios brasileiros, como: Ji-Paraná, Campo Grande, Iporá, ...

Answer (score 1):

`NoteType` significa que invés de uma instância de uma classe qualquer com que estejas trabalhando, foi recebido o valor `None`. Isso geralmente quer dizer que a função chamada falhou ou retornou um resultado inesperado.

Nesse caso, talvez possas tratar do erro de uma maneira melhor, como:

```py
try:
    location = geolocator.geocode(df['Municipio'], timeout=10)
    print(location.address)
except AttributeError:
    print("Problema com os dados ou uma falha com o Geocode."
except GeocoderTimedOut:
    print("Um erro de timeout ocorreu.")
```

Comment: Jobert, se entendi corretamente, o programa ficou assim após a modificação que você me aconselhou:

Comment: Jobert, obrigado pela sugestão, mas não deu certo ainda.... obtive a resposta:

`   File "teste3.py", line 10
    print(location.address)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent `

Comment: @RAULGBMENDES Isso geralmente quer dizer que tem alguns espaços extras na indentação na linha indicada. Verifica se essa linha tem a mesma quantidade de espaços que na linhas anteriors com relação ao bloco de código do `try`.